# Entity Framework: Migration classes missing from list of pending explicit migrations after moving them to the migrations folder

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I've inherited a project set up to use Entity Framework to set up the database schema on a fresh database.

The project initially had two different folders -- the default /Migrations folder, and one other folder -- with `DbMigration` classes.  I've moved all of these into a single folder, with the intention of using a single `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` along with a custom derived class of `DbMigrationsConfiguration` to run them all together at the same time.

However, when I run my `Update-Database` command against a fresh (blank) SQL Server database, the migrations that were not originally in the /Migrations folder don't show up at all in the list of "Applying explicit migrations" that Entity Framework tries to run.

So, my question: Why aren't the `DbMigration` classes that I moved from elsewhere into my /Migrations folder included in the list of pending explicit migrations being run when I run `Update-Database`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, the problem turned out to be that the `DbMigration` classes that I'd moved from elsewhere into the main /Migrations folder were members of a different namespace.

I changed those classes -- both the manually-created `DbMigration` class files, and their corresponding autogenerated *.Designer.cs files -- to be in the same namespace as the existing `DbMigration` classes in the /Migrations folder.

After doing that, the moved migration classes successfully started being included by Entity Framework in the list of pending explicit migrations to be applied when I ran `Update-Database`.

Comment: Thank you! you saved me from hours of searching :)